# AzureDevops Pipelines Powershell Script New-PsSession Error

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use a simple powershell script. I have such a script file like test.ps1 and its content is as follows.

```
  $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName MYPRSNLCMPTR
  Copy-Item "C:\MyFolder" -Destination "C:\" -ToSession -Recursive
```

When I right click the  test.ps1 and run with the powershell. The script is working. Copying folder on my local computer to remote computer.

When I add this script as a task in azuredevops pipeline this script gives me such an error like this:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New- 
PSSession], PSRemotin 
gTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause? What am I missing?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but looking at the error message it seems like the account the session is using does not have the permissions to edit items in C:\ destination folder. 
That's probably because it's using the computers local account. 
You could try to test this out with something like WhoAmI in the PowerShell script?

Comment: Perhaps this link may help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops